# parsing random stdClass

Tags: php

I seem to be a little lost on what to so about this, im trying to parse out some info but the stdClass is going to always be changing, so im not too sure on what to do about it and could use come guidance.

//Query

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('name', 'GOOG')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', '3')
  ->execute();
```

//This is the output

```
Array
(
    [taxonomy_term] => Array
        (
            [1868] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tid] => 1868
                )

        )

)
```

Now I can get to the tid by using

```
$result['taxonomy_term']['1868']->tid
```

but as mentioned before the the stdClass will be always changing.

Comment: So you will need to be able to get properties other than `tid`, whose names you don't know in advance?

Comment: im trying to get the properties of tid but the stdClass is always changing. So its kinda hard to do that with it constantly changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recurssive array search like this:

```
function array_searchRecursive( $needle, $haystack, $strict=false, $path=array() )
{
    if( !is_array($haystack) ) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach( $haystack as $key => $val ) {
        if( is_array($val) && $subPath = array_searchRecursive($needle, $val, $strict, $path) ) {
            $path = array_merge($path, array($key), $subPath);
            return $path;
        } elseif( (!$strict && $val == $needle) || ($strict && $val === $needle) ) {
            $path[] = $key;
            return $path;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$arr = (array) $yourObject;
$keypath = array_searchRecursive('tid', $arr);
```

**Example:**

```
$class = new stdClass;
$class->foo = 'foo';
$class->bar = 'bar';
$arr = (array) $class;
$keypath = array_searchRecursive('foo', $arr);
print_r($keypath);
```

**Results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
)
```

So now to get actual value:

```
echo $keypath[0]; // foo
```

Comment: am i using this correctly? because it keeps returning the blank. http://pastebin.com/p4nK7vWb

Comment: its actually making my page return blank, I try to figure out whats causing it, I appreciate you taking time to answer my question.